# Sending push notificationsto the FCM server not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am new to the Android Studio. Currently I am working on the FCM push notification, but the code is not sending any king of remote message to the FCM Server. When sending the remote message from the FCM server it catches the remote message, but when sending the remote message from android app to the FCM server, the app does not catches any kind of remote message back from the server. Please help.

This is my Java Code to send the remote message:

```
URL url2 = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
                    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=AIzaSyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxrjM");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

                    json.put("to", regToken);


                    JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
                    info.put("title", "New order from " + name);   // Notification title
                    info.put("body", "Order ID " + order_number); // Notification body

                    json.put("data", info);

                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    wr.write(json.toString());
                    wr.flush();
                    conn.getInputStream();

                    //Toast.makeText(ctx, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Error", "" + e);
                }
```

My service to receive the remote message;

```
 public class FireBaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                String channelId = "channel-01";
                String channelName = "Channel";
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                            channelId, channelName, importance);
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                }


                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                        .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                        .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setColor(0xffff7700)
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 100, 100, 100})
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri);
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Orders.class);

                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(Orders.class);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                                0,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        );


                notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                mNotificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());

        }

    }
```

Implemented service in the Manifest:

```
<service
            android:name=".FireBaseMsgService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: Zoe Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

```
  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                devicetoken();
                Log.e("newToken", newToken);
            }
        });
```

**After implement in your activity**:

```
  mrequestqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ContributorDetailsActivity.this);
                JSONObject mainobj = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    mainobj.put("to",token);
                    JSONObject notificationObj = new JSONObject();
                    notificationObj.put("title","Accepted Your Request");
                    notificationObj.put("body","your request is accepted by " + " " + distributorname);
                    mainobj.put("notification",notificationObj);

                    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, mainobj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.e("success", response.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(ContributorDetailsActivity.this, "successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            updatestatus();


                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("error", error.toString());

                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                            header.put("content-type", "application/json");
                            header.put("authorization", "key=your FCM key");
                            return header;
                        }
                    };
                    mrequestqueue.add(request);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    //do nothing
                }
```